# Can't update entire reactive array with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-sfc

Here's the code. No errors or anything, but the output doesn't update as expected.

[Code in Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNo9UMtuwyAQ/JUVlzgShtRtWsmyLfUfegs5uBauHYWHANMD4t+7xFUOIGaZmd3ZRD6tZXGTpCWdn9xqA3gZNguD0KuyxgVI4ORM8RqnsEYJGWZnFBxQdRBa6MloH2B0Dvonqbo09I2+X4+FgIZfq5JmC1V17AdIyGVxvG8SFZcX+krP9OOaKZxPJxR0fB8EJ0AQpLL3MUhEAOV0SwOxno3rBYmw6tJZkAHQEFKCCDl3fGl2NX/KCSV7nlqNlt280Rg5PUz/P7wgLTwqpYbpChZkCcH6lnM/T2VRN8+M++H4Ym7TAXMx6VX97cyvlw6NBSkWWehM8h/m83XO)

```html
<script setup >
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'

const arr = reactive([2,4,6])

setTimeout(()=> { arr.value = [1, 3, 5, 7] }, 500) // This doesn't work!
</script>

<template>
  <h2 v-for="v in arr"> val {{ v }}</h2>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `reactive`, you get back an object where you can set its properties without `value`. You either define an object where `arr` is a property:

```js
const state = reactive({
  arr: [2, 4, 6]
})
setTimeout(()=> {state.arr = [1,3,5,7]}, 500)
```

Or for arrays I'd suggest using `ref` instead, then the rest of your code should work:

```js
const arr = ref([2, 4, 6])
```

Comment: `reactive` doesn't update the iteration in the `v-for` for some reason even if the state is properly updated.

Comment: You probably also need to add `:key` to the `h2`

Comment: Doesn't change anything. I guess it is maybe notified differently regarding the proxy.

Comment: "Or for arrays I'd suggest using ref instead". Thanks -For some reason I thought you had to use Reactive on arrays...

Comment: @Roddy `reactive` is kinda a `ref` with some added syntactic sugar. Kinda tricky but the same thing under the hood. Have to say that I'm still confused about that one. There are also 2 schools: people using `ref` only or `ref` + `reactive`, doesn't help for sure.

Comment: Actually `ref` is using `reactive` internally, simplified: `const ref = (value) => reactive({value})`

Comment: @Thomas, is there any reason why this should be the convension?

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` can be pretty tricky regarding its context, and `reactive` also have its quirks.
Hence I do recommend using the following

```html
<script setup>
import { useTimeoutFn } from "@vueuse/core"
import { ref } from "vue"

let arr = ref([2, 4, 6])

const { start } = useTimeoutFn(() => {
  arr.value = [1, 3, 5, 7]
}, 500)

start()
</script>

<template>
  <h2 v-for="v in arr" :key="v">val {{ v }}</h2>
</template>
```

---

[`useTimeoutFn`](https://vueuse.org/shared/usetimeoutfn/#usetimeoutfn) is an official helper "hook" maintained by the Vue team.
The VueUse project is plenty of super useful functions like that, give it a try!